# MySQL / Aurora DateTime field not entering correct NOW() value (sometimes)

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-aurora

This is a big puzzle for us.

We have a table, where we have 2 columns, which both generally are the NOW DateTime value such as: 2022-07-11 09:00:00.000

However 1 column appears to randomly enter: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000 instead of the NOW DateTime value. Whereas the other column always works.

We have 2 different systems entering data in to the table, and both have the same entering issue.

Using the MySQL insert such as:

````
$value = ":CaseRef,:DueDateTime,:CreatedBy, NOW(), :AssignedTo";
    
$params = array();
$params[':CaseRef'] = $Data['CaseRef'];
$params[':DueDateTime'] = $Data['DueDateTime'];
$params[':CreatedBy'] = $Data['CreatedBy'];
$params[':DateCreated'] = $Data['DateCreated'];
$params[':AssignedTo'] = $Data['AssignedTo'];
        
$stmt = DB::prepare("INSERT INTO Data_Table ($sql) VALUES ($value)");
$stmt->execute($params);```

In our API we have this:

I understand your comment. But in the API, we have this:
$currentDatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Which populates an array:
$actionListData = [
     'CaseRef' => $caseRef,
     'DueDateTime' => $currentDatetime,
     'CreatedBy' => 0,
     'DateCreated' => $currentDatetime,
     'AssignedTo' => $assignedTo,
];

Yet when the data enters the DB table, the DueDateTime most of the time is the set DateTime and on random occasions it enters as 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000? How / Why could this happen?
````

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a parameter error since you don't have `:DateCreated` in your query. However, NOW() is different from an input date - the first is a MySQL function, the latter is a value. To figure out why DueDateTime is wrong, you'll have to see what the actual value is when you try to insert it. `NOW()` is not a valid value for binding, by the way -- it needs to be an actual date time.

Comment: Apologies I have mistyped the question with the ``` to highlight the code so the $sql had disappeared. This is part of a larger table as well, so I had edited it down to show the main key columns. 

Like I say it works about 95% of the time... and the DateCreated column works 100% of the time. So using either NOW() for the DueDateTime or if required a specific time but entered in the format of not always work?

$Data['DueDateTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: If you bind the value, you have to bind an actual value, so `$Data['DueDateTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` should be correct. However, `$Data['DueDateTime'] = 'NOW()'` would not work. If `$Data['DueDateTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` does not work, or if the value comes from a different source, then you'll have to find out what the value is that it's trying to send.

Comment: I have now bound the values as you said:
$dueDatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dateCreated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Then we also logged the data being sent for the Insert command and the datetime format was exactly correct.

As I said before the insert to the DB table, works most of the time. Today for example over 400 inserts and only 3 entered as 1970-01-01 01:00:00, and for the same 3 the DateCreated column entered correctly.

We have tried switching around the array, and the insert so the DateCreated is requested first, but still the DueDateTime goes in incorrectly.